# ASP.NET Core: duração da sessão

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-core, cookies

Fiz um programa em `ASP.NET Core` MVC, que tem a classe `Startup` como:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //...
            services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<idDataContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opts =>
            {
                opts.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                opts.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
                opts.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
            });

            //...

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, AppFeatures features)
        {
            //...
            app.UseAuthentication();
            //...
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("error"))
                    throw new Exception("Erro: caminho contém 'error'!");

                await next();
            });

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseFileServer();
        }
    }
```

Estou a indicar que a cookie do login e a cookie da sessão (com dados da minha app) duram 4h? Falta indicar isto em mais algum lado?

É que aparentemente as sessões não duram 4h no cliente. Existe algum erro?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sessão não tem uma expiração como os cookies, mas ela expira após um período de inatividade. O tempo de inatividade começa a ser contado após o recebimento da última requisição e cada nova requisição que passa pelo middleware da sessão reinicia a contagem de tempo. Seu limite padrão é 20 minutos e pode ser configurado na opção `IdleTimeout`. O `IdleTimeout` é utilizado para determinar por quanto tempo uma sessão pode ficar ociosa antes que seu conteúdo no cache do servidor seja abandonado. Essa propriedade é independente da expiração do cookie. Para habilitar o middleware da sessão, seu `Startup` deve conter um `IDistributedCache` para armazenar a sessão, uma chamada para `AddSession` em `ConfigureServices` e uma chamada para `UseSession` em `Configure`. Para o seu caso, uma sessão que expira após 4 horas de inatividade com um cache configurado em memória será parecido com o que segue abaixo:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(opts =>
        {
            opts.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
            opts.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
            opts.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
        });

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(4);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            // Make the session cookie essential
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
            //...
            app.UseAuthentication();
            //...
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("error"))
                    throw new Exception("Erro: caminho contém 'error'!");

                await next();
            });

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseFileServer();
    }
}
```

observe que a configuração `options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(4)` foi adicionada em `AddSession`. Para mais informações veja a [documentação oficial da microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-session-state).